# How to return an enum from a function in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, enums, swiftui

I want to return an `enum` from my function. For that, I need to classify a return type.

However, what is the return type if I want to return an `enum`?

My code below:

```
class Timezone {
    
    func getTimeZoneFromCountry(country: String) -> ??? {
        switch country {
        case "AU":
            return Timezone.AU
        case "US":
            return Timezone.US
        default:
            return Timezone.AU
        }
    }
   
    enum AU: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
        case AEST = "AEST"
        case AWST = "AWST"
        case ACST = "ACST"
        
        var id: AU {self}
    }
    
    enum US: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
        case CST = "CST"
        case EST = "EST"
        case MST = "MST"
        case PST = "PST"
        
        var id: US {self}
    }

}
```

I'm trying to dynamically populate a `Picker`:

```
struct TimeZonePicker: View {
    @Binding var country: String // AU or US
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Timezone", selection: $country) {
            ForEach(*Dynamic enum here*) { i in
                Text(String(i.rawValue))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: New view with @Sweeper's dynamic solution:

```
var body: some View {
    Picker("Timezone", selection: $country) {
        ForEach(Timezone.getTimeZoneFromCountry(country: country)) { i in
            Text(String(i.rawValue))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you want to use `getTimeZoneFromCountry`? This looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Added in my edits. I'm trying to dynamically populate a `Picker` view @Sweeper

Comment: In that case, why are `AU` and `US` separate enums? You can just have one `Timezone` enum with all the cases, and have `getTimeZoneFromCountry` return an array of `Timezone`, containing only the cases for that part of the world.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a single enum, and have `getTimeZoneFromCountry` return only certain cases of the enum:

```
enum Timezone: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: Timezone { self }
    
    static func getTimeZoneFromCountry(country: String) -> [Timezone] {
        switch country {
        case "AU":
            return Timezone.AU
        case "US":
            return Timezone.US
        default:
            return Timezone.AU
        }
    }
    case AEST = "AEST"
    case AWST = "AWST"
    case ACST = "ACST"

    case CST = "CST"
    case EST = "EST"
    case MST = "MST"
    case PST = "PST"
    
    static let AU: [Timezone] = [.AEST, .AWST, .ACST]
    static let US: [Timezone] = [.CST, .EST, .MST, .PST]

}
```

Comment: why does it have to conform to CaseIterable protocol ?

Comment: @VincentJoy Doesn't have to, but OP's `US` and `AU` enums did, so I did too.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is a good fit but for those who are care about the  quality of the code, these are extra:

### First of all

You don't need to define the raw value for `String` based `enum`s when the raw value and the case is exactly the same! So

```
case AEST = "AEST"
```

is exactly equal to:

```
case AEST
```

### Second of all:

You can extend the `Identifiable` itself to have an implementation to all `RawRepresentable`s:

```
extension Identifiable where Self: RawRepresentable {
    var id: Self { self }
}
```

### Third of all:

You can use associated value in the enum for sectioning values like:

```
enum Timezone {
    case au([AU])
    case us([US])
,,,
}
```

### Forth of all:

Try to avoid unknown behaviors by avoiding default assigning. You can have an optional init instead:

```
init?(raw: String) {
    switch raw.lowercased() {
    case "au": self = .au(AU.allCases)
    case "us": self = .us(US.allCases)
    default: return nil
    }
}
```

### Fifth of all:

Don't forget that strings are case sensitive! Try handle the sensitivity. for  example check for `lowercased`.

---

## So the full code would be something like:

```
enum Timezone {
    init?(raw: String) {
        switch raw.lowercased() {
        case "au": self = .au(AU.allCases)
        case "us": self = .us(US.allCases)
        default: return nil
        }
    }

    case au([AU])
    case us([US])

    enum AU: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
        case AEST
        case AWST
        case ACST
    }

    enum US: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
        case CST
        case EST
        case MST
        case PST
    }
}

extension Identifiable where Self: RawRepresentable {
    var id: Self { self }
}
```

Comment: Neat and clean. No internal use of textual TimeZone. But how do I get rid of the "TimeZoneSample_Contents.Timezone3.US." part?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: print(Timezone(raw: "us")) gives - Optional(TimeZoneSample_Contents.Timezone.us([TimeZoneSample_Contents.Timezone.US.CST, ....])) - for the picker the TS and me need only the TimeZones like 'CST' e.t.c.

Comment: Most of  the statement is the namespace. Try using something like this: 
```Timezone(raw: "us").map { timezone -> [String] in
    switch timezone {
    case .au(let zones): return zones.map { $0.rawValue }
    case .us(let zones): return zones.map { $0.rawValue }
    }
}```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe, you could work this out into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give return type as array of string and inside switch case return the array of strings from enum's allCase.

```
class Timezone {
    
    func getTimeZoneFromCountry(country: String) -> [String] {
    switch country {
    case "AU":
        return Timezone.AU.allCases.map({$0.rawValue})
    case "US":
    return Timezone.US.allCases.map({$0.rawValue})
    default:
    return Timezone.AU.allCases.map({$0.rawValue})
    }
    }
    
    enum AU: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
        case AEST = "AEST"
        case AWST = "AWST"
        case ACST = "ACST"
        
        var id: AU {self}
    }
    
    enum US: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
        case CST = "CST"
        case EST = "EST"
        case MST = "MST"
        case PST = "PST"
        
        var id: US {self}
    }
    
}
```